# How to create one generic vf page and use in standard page layout of multiple objects?

Tags: visualforce, page-layout

I want to show a simple vf page on detail page layout of 10 objects by dragging the vf on to the page layout. Right now, I am writing one vf page for each object as below:

**AccountVf.page**:

```
<apex:page StandardController="Account">
    We are on Account Page
</apex:page>
```

**ContactVf.page**:

```
<apex:page StandardController="Contact">
    We are on Contact Page
</apex:page>
```

Is there a easy way of doing this, instead of creating new visualforce page for each object?

Answer (score 2):

No. If you want common markup to share across pages for multiple objects, you would move the common markup into a `Visualforce Component` instead of `Visualforce Page`.

```
<apex:component>
    <apex:attribute name="sObjectType" type="String" required="true"
        description="Type of SObject for which this component renders" />

    We are on {!sObjectType} Page
</apex:component>
```

Then you'd use this component in your pages.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <c:MyComponent sObjectType="Account" />
</apex:page>
```